# React component is not showing up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

***PROBLEM***

So I have two files in my auth folder one is called Signin and the other is called SignUp These two files are identical except for the names. all of the tags are the same the only difference is the naming of the file and the component.

For some reason though I am only ever able to see the SignIn component when the other component is created in the exact same way.

Here is the SignUp component, the one that is not being rendered.

```
import Axios from "axios";
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import '../comStyles.css'
import UserContext from '../../context/UserContext';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


export default function SignUp() {



    const [email, setEmail] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();

    const { setUserData } = useContext(UserContext);
    const history = useHistory();


    const submit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const existingUser = {email, password};
      const loginRes = await Axios.post("http://localhost:8174/user/login", existingUser);
      setUserData({
        token: loginRes.data.token,
        user: loginRes.data.token
      });
      localStorage.setItem("auth-token", loginRes.data.token);
      history.push("/");
    }
  

      return (
        // <div className="w-50 bg-black signinbox align-items-center justify-content-center h-50">
        <div className="signinbox w-50 h-50">

       
          <div className="shadow-lg bg-black p-3">
            <h1 className="title my-2">UNT LMS</h1>
              <form onSubmit={submit}>
                <input id="login-email" className="form-control mr-sm-7 my-3" type="email" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Search" onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                <input className="form-control mr-sm-7 shadow-lg bg-black rounded" type="password" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Search" onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
                <button className="bg-black signinbutton btn btn-outline-success my-4" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
              </form>
          </div>
          
        </div>



      );
    




}
```

It is being rendered by another component called AuthLinks like this. (Same way for SignIn)

```
<Link to="/SignUp" className="nav-link">
                        Sign Up
                    </Link>
```

This creates a link that can take you to /SignUp component or page.

However as it does in fact change the url to /SignUp there is nothing to show on the page. The component is failing to render even though if I go to /SignIn it renders to the browser fine.

Here are how the routes are setup in App.js

```
import { NavBar } from './components';
import SignIn from './components/auth/SignIn';
import SignUp from './components/auth/SignUp';
```

```
<Switch>
            <Route path="/Books/list" exact component={BooksList} />
            <Route path="/Books/create" exact component={BooksInsert} />
            <Route path="/Books/update/:id" exact component={BooksUpdate} />

            <div className="vh-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <Route path="/SignIn" exact component={SignIn} />
            </div>
            <div className="vh-100 align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <Route path="/SignUp" exact component={SignUp} />
                
            </div>
        </Switch>
```

[image]

[image]

**Trouble Shooting**

I have read other questions about the component and their capitalization. I don't think that this is the case for this question. As I have tried creating a whole new file called Register and changing everything to /Register.

I tried using Lorem ipsum in case the text or anything was just hiding behind the navbar.

I tried making it the full width and height of the screen the VH as well.

tried to refresh the page.
restarted the server on port 3000

Comment: Is it working if both the route and path are lower case?

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything if I change it to lower case. I am getting a warning or error in the browser. index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `computedMatch` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `computedmatch` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: place `console.log("test")` right in the beginning of the component, to see if it's getting to the component.

Comment: Could you share your source code ?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the submit function here? `<form onSubmit={submit}>`  Perhaps it gets triggered immeditately.